# Ubuntu 12.04 Asus Eee PC 1005 weird keyboard

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, eeepc

After upgrading to 12.04 on my netbook the keyboard got weird behaviour

Before logging in to any session everything's OK (i tested the input in vt1) but as i log in with any session (unity or unity-2d) keyboard behaves as if Fn key was pressed (i got numbers and special symbols instead of normal chars. I think the problem may be in acpi support, but i don't know where to start exactly.

I will appreciate any help =)

P.S. Sorry for my english - I am not a native speaker =)

Comment: I am having the same issue with the quote ´´´ key I have to press it twice to get it to work and it happens on every keyboard that I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy, just had to toggle num key (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Num</kbd>)